# recursively putting array elements in their own array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to create a function that puts each array element in its own array, recursively.

I think my base case is correct, but my recursive call doesn't appear to be working. any insight?

```
function ownList(arr){
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    arr[0] = [arr[0]];
    return;
  } else {
    return arr[0].concat(ownList(arr.slice(1)));
  }    
}
var arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(ownList(arr))// returns []
//should return [[1],[2],[3]]
```

Here I'm trying to put each pair in it's own list (recursive only). This code below is correct (update)

```
function ownListPair(arr){
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return arr;
  else if(arr.length === 1)
    return [[arr[0], 0]];
  else 
    return [[arr[0], arr[1]]].concat(ownListPair(arr.slice(2)));
}

// var arr = [3,6,8,1,5]
var arr = [2,7,8,3,1,4]
//returns [ [ 2, 7 ], [ 8, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ]]
console.log(ownListPair(arr))
```

Comment: Consider these 2 things: you're creating `newArr` each time you call the function, and one case does not return an array. If it's truly recursive, I would think any return should be of the same type.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Does the OP even need `return newArr`? you should only need that 1 return in the `if` because that is what is actually returning the finished array.

Comment: @Adjit: Honestly, if I were building it I'd be returning the lowest level array object available in the function and inserting that in the top level array. I've never been all that great with recursion myself though.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I edited my code to take your comments into account, but still not seeing it.

Comment: @devdropper87 it would be really helpful if you gave us some idea of what the desired outcome for this code is -- some sample input and desired output.

Comment: @necaris whoops! had that originally but deleted it accidentally during an edit. just re-edited to include that.

Comment: You say recursively, but your example is only a one-layer deep array. Can you show some more complex expected inputs and outputs? For example, should input `[1, 2, 3, ["a", "b", "c"]]` yield `[[1], [2], [3], ["a"], ["b"], ["c"]]`? Is that the idea?

Comment: No. According to the solution you provided yourself, it is not correct. How I understand it you are not interested in recursive data structures but only in an implementation that uses recursion for this problem: Wrap the elements of ONE array in their own arrays.

Comment: I edited your question to make this clear. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @lex82 No, I think that the clarification in the comments is ample to illustrate what the desired input/output it. But even if that is incorrect, you should not in my opinion edit questions this aggressively until it has been ascertained what it is that the author is asking, not editing + "Please tell me if I'm wrong". Clarify, don't assume.

Comment: @thomas. Yes, probably you are right. Actually I was hesitating first. However, when I saw that the author has already answered his own question, I decided it would be better to change the question to at least match his own answer to avoid further confusion and more wasted time from people trying to help. Anyway, the "Please tell me if I'm wrong" is certainly inconsistent with my action.

Comment: thanks for the help and apologies for any confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer this solution for several reasons:

```
function ownList(a) {
  return a.length == 0
      ? []
      : [[a[0]]].concat(ownList(a.slice(1))) 
}
```

- It's shorter and more concise
- It works for empty arrays as well
- The actual wrapping happens only once in the last line. Treating `length == 1` separately -- as suggested by others -- is not necessary.

Comment: thanks, love it and makes alot of sense. I'm trying to do something similar, but instead put pairs in their own list. if an element doesn't have a pair, add a zero in.  I'm updating the code above. I'm so close! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your solution fails for arrays with an even number of elements. You will eventually run into the case that length is  < 2 but then the array is empty and you are trying to access the first element.

Comment: Well then it works? If yes, please don't put the correct code in the question or make sure it is clear that it is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

It would more appropriate to make a length of 0 be the null case. Then you just have to get the brackets right. The thing on the left side of the `concat` should be an array consisting of the array containing the first element.

```
function ownList(arr) {
  return arr.length ? [[arr[0]]].concat(ownList(arr.slice(1))) : [];
}
```

Here's an alternative, take your pick:

```
function ownList(arr) {
  return arr.length ? [[arr.shift()]] . concat(ownList(arr)) : [];
}
```

Using a bit of ES6 magic for readability:

```
function ownList([head, ...tail]) {
  return head === undefined ? [] : [[head]] . concat(ownList(tail));
}
```

Here the `[head, ...tail]` is using *parameter destructuring* which pulls the argument apart into its first element (head) and an array of remaining ones (tail).

Instead of `concat` you could also use the array constructor:

```
function ownList([head, ...tail]) {
  return head === undefined ? [] : Array([head], ...ownList(tail));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your basic assumption is wrong. What you need to do is check if each item in the array is an array, if not just add the item to the new array, if so have the function run itself on the array item.

That is recursion.

This code does that kind of recursion...

```
function ownList(arr)
{
    var newArr = [];
    var length = arr.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (typeof(arr[i]) === 'object') {
            newArr.push(ownList(arr[i]));
            continue;
        }

        newArr.push([arr[i]]);
    }

    return newArr;
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(ownList(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, ["a", "b", "c", ["str"]]], 
result = [];

function flatten(input){

  input.forEach(function(el){
    if(Array.isArray(el)){
      flatten(el)
    }else{
      result.push([el]);
    }
  });

}

flatten(arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
//[[1],[2],[3],["a"],["b"],["c"],["str"]]
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hoviqisuwo/edit?html,js,output)

Edit:

```
var result = [];
function flatten(input){
  if (input.length === 0){
    console.log( "result", result ); //[[1],[2],[3],["a"],["b"],["c"],["str"]]
    return;
  }
  //if zeroth el of input !array, push to result
  if (!Array.isArray(input[0])){
    result.push(input.splice(0, 1));
    flatten(input);  
  }else{
    flatten(input[0]); //else, give input[0] back to flatten
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  var arr = [1, 2, 3, ["a", "b", "c", ["str"]]];
    flatten(arr); 
}
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/raviyumuzo/edit?js,output)

Comment: that would technically work but not trying to take an iterative approach this is an exercise to make recursion more intuitive - I was told to try this without any for loops. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @devdropper87 I've added a solution that does not use loops. Is this more what you are looking for. I feel like I may be missing some of the criteria still, so I hope this is closer to what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

After struggling through this today, turns out that this works :)

```
function ownList(arr){
  //base case:

  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return [arr];
  }

 //recurse
 //have to do two brackets here --> (arr.slice(0,1)) since length > 1
  return [arr.slice(0,1)].concat(ownList(arr.slice(1)));

}

var arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(ownList(arr))// returns [[1],[2],[3]]
```

Comment: This does not work with multiple layers of nested arrays which in your response to my comment you indicated was a requirement. `[1, 2, 3, ["a", "b", "c", ["str"]]]; => [[1],[2],[3],[["a","b","c",["str"]]]]`

Comment: This fails on `ownList([])`, because you have chosen a length of 1 to be the null case; a length of 0 would be better.